# Not able to plot graphs on GNUPLOT in Linux

Tags: graph, plot, gnuplot

I have installed GNU plot 4.6.3 in my Linux machine but not able to see graphs.
I googled it and find that terminal settings should be set first.

When I use set terminal it shows many options but not png, gif, etc.

Available terminal types:

```
    canvas  HTML Canvas object
              cgm  Computer Graphics Metafile
          context  ConTeXt with MetaFun (for PDF documents)
            corel  EPS format for CorelDRAW
             dumb  ascii art for anything that prints text
              dxf  dxf-file for AutoCad (default size 120x80)
            eepic  EEPIC -- extended LaTeX picture environment
              emf  Enhanced Metafile format
            emtex  LaTeX picture environment with emTeX specials
         epslatex  LaTeX picture environment using graphicx package
              fig  FIG graphics language for XFIG graphics editor
             gpic  GPIC -- Produce graphs in groff using the gpic preprocessor
          hp2623A  HP2623A and maybe others
           hp2648  HP2648 and HP2647
             hpgl  HP7475 and relatives [number of pens] [eject]
           imagen  Imagen laser printer
            latex  LaTeX picture environment
               mf  Metafont plotting standard
              mif  Frame maker MIF 3.00 format
               mp  MetaPost plotting standard
             pcl5  HP Designjet 750C, HP Laserjet III/IV, etc.

imagen  Imagen laser printer
            latex  LaTeX picture environment
               mf  Metafont plotting standard
              mif  Frame maker MIF 3.00 format
               mp  MetaPost plotting standard
             pcl5  HP Designjet 750C, HP Laserjet III/IV, etc. (many options)
Press return for more: return
       postscript  PostScript graphics, including EPSF embedded files (*.eps)
          pslatex  LaTeX picture environment with PostScript \specials
            pstex  plain TeX with PostScript \specials
         pstricks  LaTeX picture environment with PSTricks macros
              qms  QMS/QUIC Laser printer (also Talaris 1200 and others)
            regis  REGIS graphics language
              svg  W3C Scalable Vector Graphics driver
          tek40xx  Tektronix 4010 and others; most TEK emulators
          tek410x  Tektronix 4106, 4107, 4109 and 420X terminals
          texdraw  LaTeX texdraw environment
             tgif  TGIF X11 [mode] [x,y] [dashed] ["font" [fontsize]]
         tkcanvas  Tk/Tcl canvas widget [perltk] [interactive]
             tpic  TPIC -- LaTeX picture environment with tpic \specials
          unknown  Unknown terminal type - not a plotting device
            vttek  VT-like tek40xx terminal emulator
            xterm  Xterm Tektronix 4014 Mode
```

How can I possibly see my graphs ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: How did you install gnuplot, and on which Linux distribution?

Answer (score 0):

You need a x11 or wxt terminal. So if you are installing from source code use option

```
./configure --with-x
```

If you are installing debian package use gnuplot-x11 package.